# Lucene query parser automatic prefix

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Apache Lucene 8.9.0 to parse queries that are entered by humans. I am using the `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.MultiFieldQueryParser` which works very well so far.

However I would like to automatically use the prefix notation (`*`) for all terms in the query, instead of searching for exact terms, so the humans entering the queries don't have to type the `*` after each term.

An example query could be: `author:(murphy OR remender) AND batman AND release_date:1999`, which should be transformed to `author:(murphy* OR remender*) AND batman* AND release_date:1999*`.

Is there any way to do this with the Lucene query parsers ? I checked the classic and standard query parser, but couldn't find any option to do so.

If there was a way to decide which fields could automatically be prefixed, that would be even better.